# HDR Images I pack go missing in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blend-files

I am using an HDR to light my world in a .blend file. It works fine normally, but when I pack it it mysteriously goes missing during render time. Why is this?

Here is a .blend file demonstrating it:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37691

Notice how you can unpack the HDR and it loads fine in the UV Editor, but rendering it's gone!

Comment: Your example file worked just fine for me when rendering. Maybe try it again?

Comment: No, doesn't work for me. Could you see the HDR, or did everything turn out pink?

Comment: I could see the HDR image. No pink. http://i.imgur.com/xeyCuJ1.png?1

Comment: Could it be a problem with my computer? I always seem to get random problems no one else does.

Comment: Try opening a new blender file, switch to cycles, open an HDR for your environment lighting, and pack it. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Strange thing is that it doesn't. Did you have to unpack the HDR?

Comment: Nope. Packing just takes the files from your computer and adds them to the .blend file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved when I switched to the CPU renderer. I am guessing that OpenCL is at fault, because it happened during GPU rendering. More information [here](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html).

Looks like GPU OpenCL is lacking many features, so I recommend using CPU renderer for now.

Comment: You could read in the wiki about [no support for HDR textures on OpenCL](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-features-and-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

In the Render View window, select Display > Color Management... The viewColorManager Attribute Editor appears.
Select the color profile for your image source and your display output using the Image Color Profile and Display Color Profile drop-down menus.
Specify your custom calibration file or color transformation file in the LUT file attribute. You can also use this attribute to apply a color grading effect.
What editor are you use? try out [aurora](http://aurorahdr.com/getstarted/masking-brush-aurora-hdr)
Is it mac or win?